# Проблема с открытием View Controller "Assertion failure in.."

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

При нажатии на кнопку должен открыть View Controller.

```
- (IBAction)open:(id)sender {
ExtendedFormViewController *extView = [[ExtendedFormViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExtendedFormViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:extView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Но вылетает ошибка:

`*** Assertion failure in -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UIWindowController.m:223`

Что странно, такая ошибка вылетает если я пытаюсь загрузить новые, созданные сейчас View Controller'ы. Если попробовать загрузить созданный ранее контроллер, то все получается нормально.

Попробовал очистить Derived Data, но безуспешно. Такое ощущение, будто я превысил лимит вью контроллеров в проекте:/

**Update:** Может ли быть в ошибка в этом:

При запуске приложения, самым первым загружается View Controller(форма регистрации, если пользователь не зарегистрирован), который в методе  `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` проверяет в NSUserDefaults, заполнено ли поле @"mode", и если оно не пустое, то загружет соответствующий вью контроллер.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *mode = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"mode"];
if ([mode isEqualToString:@"client"]) {
        ClientViewController *secondViewController = [[ClientViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ClientViewController"               bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    } else if ([mode isEqualToString:@"driver"]) {
        DriverViewController *secondViewController = [[DriverViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DriverViewController"               bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
```

А в  ClientViewController, есть этот метод `open`, который не работает.
Может я неправильно использую presentViewController?

Еще похожая проблема была в этой теме, которую заминусовали - [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/288609/objective-c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)

**UPDATE 2:** **Проблема решена. Дети, всегда проверяйте от какого класса наследуется контроллер. Я вместо UIViewController, наследовал от обычного ViewController.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какой-то исполняемый код, выполняется до того как контроллер прогрузится. проверьте реализацию ExtendedFormViewController точно ли он наследуется от UIViewController.
и второе, может быть нарушена иерархия вьюх и контролов, хотя это врядли. 
еще можете попробывать очистить проект CMD+shift+K (+option для полной очистки билд папки)
А, ну и дебагер в помощь.

Comment: Блин, простите за нубство! Я дурак, наследовал его от класса ViewController, а не от UIViewController. 
Эта ошибка попортила мне много нервов, впредь буду внимательней:)